# How does Firebase `observeEventType` method get data in iOS?

Tags: ios, firebase

How does Firebase (or other similar Framework) `observeEventType` method get data?
I know how to use it, but how it works under hood?
Does Firebase server send data to a some port, or app regularly ask a server for changes?
Does it generate traffic on standby?

Answer (score 0):

From Firebase Documentation:

> Instead of typical HTTP requests, the Firebase Realtime Database uses data synchronization—every time data changes, any connected device receives that update within milliseconds. Provide collaborative and immersive experiences without thinking about networking code.

[Link to Docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/#how_does_it_work)

From this, I gather that Firebase has various endpoints that evaluate a request or subscription type and hand back JSON in that way.